# Javascript + SVG: Adding mouse events to SVG in object

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm making a digitized board game. At a certain stage in the game, I need to add a mouse hover event that changes the object's stroke color when you hover over it. So, adding mouse events to the SVG via JavaScript seemed like the way to go.

Here is my attempt.

```
// wait until all the resources are loaded
    window.addEventListener("load", findSVGElements, false);

    // fetches the document for the given embedding_element
    function getSubDocument(embedding_element) {
        if (embedding_element.contentDocument) {
            return embedding_element.contentDocument;
        } else {
            var subdoc = null;
            try {
                subdoc = embedding_element.getSVGDocument();
            } catch(e) {}
            return subdoc;
        }
    }

    function findSVGElements() {
        var board = document.getElementById("board");
        var subdoc = getSubDocument(board);
            if (subdoc)
                for (i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
                    var city = subdoc.getElementById(String(i));
                    city.addEventListener("mouseover", city.setAttribute('stroke', 'lime') );
                    city.addEventListener("mouseout", city.setAttribute('stroke', 'ivory') );
                }
    }
```

The script is adapted from a script, [get-embedded-svg-document-script.html](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html), which is a little bit of overkill, but works. Playing around with changing different attribute changes, it seems like the script gets stuck on the `mouseout` event and doesn't read or evecute the `mouseover` event, but that could be wrong. Manipulating SVGs is pretty new territory for me. The scripts works perfectly if I'm simply setting the attribute. I just can't figure out how to get the mouse events to behave.

Comment: In general, you are much better off having the color change on hover be done in CSS. You can add/remove/change a `class` on the elements that enables/disables the color changing upon `hover` at the time you wish to change from not changing to changing and back.

Comment: OP can't really use CSS because he is clearly embedding the SVG via an `<object>`.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau The SVG is embedded in an object. I did that because the SVG is reasonably complicated with filters on a number of objects and I don't want to clutter the HTML. However, I did manage to put some CSS styling within the SVG itself. I made an `unavailable` class and `available` class,  the latter with a `hover` pseudo-class. I haven't implemented a script for switching classes yet, but the color change does work. I'm noticing what seems like a tiny bit of lag on the switch though. Not sure if I just need to work on optimizing the SVG, if the CSS is slow, or if I'm just tired.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you are defining your event handlers.  They should be functions, not statements.  Try:

```
city.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { this.setAttribute('stroke', 'lime') });
city.addEventListener("mouseout", function() { this.setAttribute('stroke', 'ivory') ));
```